# Vuejs- I want to get a simple button value so when it's clicked two radio buttons are shown

Tags: vue.js, antd, vuejs3, antdv

I'm trying to do something, I don't know where to start. So basically it's a submit button if it's clicked I have to get two radio buttons shown to chose from one of them, when it's not only the submit button is present . for now I only have this code where all my buttons are shown with no condition cuz I don't know how or where to use it. Can u help me out please? I'm using Ant design vue for designing that's why I have a- attributes .
here's the code:

```
<template>
   <a-button type="primary" class="mb-4 text-center  float-right ">Reject</a-button>  
    <a-button type="primary" class="mb-4 text-center mr-1 float-right" >Confirm</a-button>

   <a-radio-group name="radioGroup" class="float-right">
 <a-radio value="1">A</a-radio>
<a-radio value="2">B</a-radio>
      </a-radio-group>


  </template>

    <script>
     import { defineComponent, onMounted, reactive, ref, unref, toRaw } from 'vue'
      export default {
      name :'Okbutton',

      }
     </script>
```

Comment: initially which of the buttons need to be shown  before clicking?

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to add a v-if or v-show on your radio group and make a boolean to switch between showing them or not.

```html
  <a-radio-group v-if="showRadio" name="radioGroup" class="float-right">
    <a-radio value="1">A</a-radio>
    <a-radio value="2">B</a-radio>
  </a-radio-group>
```

I have named the boolean `showRadio`  in this example. You will need to create this boolean in your data or setup (depending on your structure). Whenever you want to show the radio button you just set `showRadio` to true.